# Golang : Escaping single quotes

Tags: go, escaping, backslash, quote

Is there a way to escape single quotes in go?

The following:

```
str := "I'm Bob, and I'm 25."
str = strings.Replace(str, "'", "\'", -1)
```

Gives the error: unknown escape sequence: '

I would like str to be

```
"I\'m Bob, and I\'m 25."
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You need to ALSO escape the slash in strings.Replace.

```
str := "I'm Bob, and I'm 25."
str = strings.ReplaceAll(str, "'", "\\'")
```

https://play.golang.org/p/BPtU2r8dXrs

Answer (score 13):

+to @KeylorSanchez answer: your can wrap replace string in back-ticks:

```
strings.ReplaceAll(str, "'", `\'`)
```

Comment: Even the first string can be in backquote. In my case i had to replace \" with " in my dbjson variable
dbjson = strings.Replace(dbjson, \`\"\`, \`"\`, -1)

This answer helped me to get there :)

Answer (score 1):

```
// addslashes()
func Addslashes(str string) string {
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    for _, char := range str {
        switch char {
        case '\'':
            buf.WriteRune('\\')
        }
        buf.WriteRune(char)
    }
    return buf.String()
}
```

If you want to escaping single/double quotes or backlash, you can refer to https://github.com/syyongx/php2go

Comment: Probably best to use `var buf strings.Builder` (instead of `bytes.Buffer`) in this case. It has the same methods, so no other changes needed

Answer (score 0):

`strings.Replacer` can be used to escape a number of different characters at once. Also handy if you want to reuse the same logic in different places.

```golang
quoteEscaper := strings.NewReplacer(`'`, `\'`, `"`, `\"`)
str := `They call me "Bob", and I'm 25.`
str = quoteEscaper.Replace(str)
```

https://go.dev/play/p/6IFecrHmN3z